# Where are my coins after restart of blockchain and transactions (Multibit)

Tags: multibit

One of my transactions didn't get confirmed. So I followed this: http://multibit.org/help_resetBlockchain.html

But now my coins are gone :-S where can I find them?

Answer (score 1):

The transactions for your coins are stored on the blockchain.
What MultiBit has is the private keys that control whether you can spend them.

When you do a reset blockchain MultiBit resyncs to what is on the blockchain and shows you the transactions it finds.

You can always export you private keys and pull them into blockchain.info if you want - there is a help topic specifically for this.

Comment: Thanks @jim618 but there is one thing I don't understand. When I revert this. I can see an amount in Multibit _but_ not in Blockchain... (ofcourse I've imported the keys into blockchain)
I leave it for now, can I assume that -in the end- my transaction will be completed?